# Issue with Enum usage

Tags: c++, enums, identifier

I have an issue with Enum (and I guess its usage): I've declared an Enum in a class and I'm trying to use it in its subclass. Here the (abstract) superclass:

```
//Function.h
class Function {
public:
    enum FunctionType {
        constant,
        variable,
        sum,
        mul
    };
    ...
    virtual FunctionType getType();
};
```

here one of its subclass:

```
//Const.h
#include "Function.h"

#ifndef CONST_H_
#define CONST_H_

class Const:public Function {
    ....
public:
    Const(double x);
    ....
    Function::FunctionType getType();
    ....
    ~Const();
};

#endif /* CONST_H_ */
```

and its implementation:

```
//Const.cpp
#include "Const.h"
#include "Function.h"


Function::FunctionType Const::getType(){
    return Function::FunctionType::constant;
}
....
```

The compiler throw the following error:

```
error: ‘Function::FunctionType’ is not a class or namespace
return Function::FunctionType::constant;
                 ^
```

I'm not able to find out why I have this error, and what's wrong with this code that sounds to me easy and sound (and of course it is not).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To qualify an enum value, you don't use the enum type name:

```
enum enum_t { ENUM_VALUE };
auto e = ENUM_VALUE; // no enum_t::
```

In your case, the solution is:

```
struct Function {
    enum FunctionType {
        constant
    };
    virtual FunctionType getType();
};

struct Const : Function {
    Function::FunctionType getType() { return Function::constant; }
};
```

---

The fact that `Function::FunctionType::constant` is an error comes from enums being a C feature to declare constants. From the [cppreference.com page on the enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), one can read:

> #### Unscoped enumeration
>
> `enum name { enumerator = constexpr , enumerator = constexpr , ... }`     (1)
>   1) Declares an *unscoped enumeration* type whose underlying type is not fixed (in this case, the underlying type is either int or, if not all enumerator values can be represented as int, an implementation-defined larger integral type that can represent all enumerator values. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0).

If you want to use strongly typed, scoped enums, see [@Angrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082488/5470596) answer and `enum class`.

Comment: note that `Function::` is a bit redundant here, but it make the reading easier when there's a lot of classes and files.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, now this error seems to be gone. I still have to understand why it is an error to write FunctionType.constant or FunctionType::constant...

Comment: @Samuele I expanded my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 4):

[@YSC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082248/1782465) is 100% correct in explaining the error you're getting.

To add a bit broader context, the syntax you originally intended to use is supported starting from C++11 in the form of *scoped enumerations.* These are enumerations where implicit conversions to/from integers are not available, and the names of the enumerators are within the scope of the enumeration. They are introduced by the syntax `enum class`.

This is in contrast to unscoped enumerations (what you get with just using `enum`), where no such scoping rules exist. The enumeration name simply does not introduce scope, so using it on the left-hand side of the scope resolution operator `::` is an error.

You could use a scoped enumeration in your code like this:

```
class Function {
public:
    enum class FunctionType {
        constant,
        variable,
        sum,
        mul
    };
    ...
    virtual FunctionType getType();
};

Function::FunctionType Const::getType(){
    return Function::FunctionType::constant;
}
```

Note that qualifying `FunctionType::constant` as `Function::FunctionType::constant` is not necessary within a class derived from `Function`; access to all members inherited from `Function` is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return Function::constant;
```

Instead of:

```
return Function::FunctionType::constant;
```

Comment: I had this error with this solution: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
  return Function::FunctionType.constant;